# If $f(x):[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then there need not exist a maximum in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, examples-counterexamples, maxima-minima

If $f(x):[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then does there exist a maximum in $[0,\infty)$ of $f$?

I think it should, but not sure how to prove it. Now, if there does not exist a maximum, it should either diverge at $0$ (by continuity) or oscillate infinitely at $0$. But, it is well defined on the closed interval $[0,\infty)$. Any examples of this kind? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $f(x)=\arctan(x)-\pi/2$.

Comment: What you can prove is that $|f(x)|$ has a maximum under your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider the case

- $f(x)=-(1+x)e^{-x}$

Note that to guarantee a maximum by EVT we need to set $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Just take $f(x)=-\frac1{x+1}$. It has no maximum.

Comment: But is not $0$ a maximum?

Comment: @vidyarthi... No since the limit at plus infinity is  $0>-1$

Comment: How can it be a maximum? The number $0$ does not belong to the range of $f$, which is $[-1,0)$.

Comment: @vidyarthi $0$ is a supremum